# DbContext.Set<TEntity> Returns Derived Class Type

Tags: entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I am using entity framework code first, I have 2 entities declared like so:

```
[Table("BaseTable")]    
public class BaseEntity
{
    public string SomeProperty{get; set;}
}

[Table("DerivedTable")]
public class DerivedEntity
 : BaseEntity
{
     public string SomeOtherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

The problem is when I call the generic set method on the dbcontext it always returns the entities as `DerivedEntity` types. (EF is setting up the correct table mapping in the database just not returing the expected entity type from the `set()` method)

```
DbContext.Set<BaseEntity>();
```

How can I force `Set<BaseEntity>();` to return the entities as type `BaseEntity` so I can only update that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. EF works on entity level not on table level. So if your entity is of type `DerivedEntity` it will never be loaded as `BaseEntity` only. When you modify attached entity EF will build update command only for modified columns so it should not modify your second table if you are only changing property from `BaseEntity` table.